# Mounted Push is not redirecting from landing page but refresh is working

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have App.vue file that I mounted function will redirect to maintenance page if maintenance set to true. When home page is landing it is not redirecting but when I do refresh the page it redirect to maintenance page.

```
mounted() {
    const siteIsMaintenanceMode = this.$store.getters.getMaintenancMode;
    if (siteIsMaintenanceMode) {
        this.$router.push({ path: "/maintenance" });
    }
    this.preloadRoutes();
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `beforeMounted` method and bind data variable in `data` object as below;

```
data() {
  return {
    siteIsMaintenanceMode: this.$store.getters.getMaintenancMode
  };
},
beforeMount(){
  if (siteIsMaintenanceMode) {
    this.$router.push({ path: "/maintenance" });
  }
},
mounted() {
  this.preloadRoutes()
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: still not redirecting from the landing page. but when I do refresh the landing page, then it works.

Comment: Try redirecting like this: router.push({ name: "yourroutename"}) or just router.push("yourroutename")

Comment: Reference url: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-routes.html